# Is the proposition " if $ f( a x ) = f( x/a) $ then prove $ a = \pm 1 $" be right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can the solution  a = $ \pm 1 $   for the functional equation:

$ f( a\, x )  =  f( x/a)  $ be correct?

Comment: it is a correct solution, but it may not be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. For a constant function, the equality holds for any values of $a$.

Comment: That means for no function with a changing dependent variable ?